# Creating shiny outputs from custom html inputs

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

Why is the `observeEvent()` not getting triggered when i use `tags$button` with a corresponding id, but it is when i use `actionButton` with an inputId. Where is the difference and how can i make my custom html `tags$button` to be an actual "event"?

This does not work:

```
library(shiny)
if (interactive()) {
  options(device.ask.default = FALSE)
  
  ui = fluidPage(
    
    tags$button(id = "action", "BTN"),
    plotOutput(outputId = "plot"))    
  
  server = function(input, output, session){
    
    observeEvent(input$action, {
      
      output$plot = renderPlot({
        hist(iris$Sepal.Length)})
    })
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

This does:

```
library(shiny)
if (interactive()) {
  options(device.ask.default = FALSE)
  
  ui = fluidPage(
    
    actionButton(inputId = "action", label = "BTN"),
    plotOutput(outputId = "plot"))    
  
  server = function(input, output, session){
    
    observeEvent(input$action, {
      
      output$plot = renderPlot({
        hist(iris$Sepal.Length)})
    })
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you add the action-button class to your button

```
tags$button(id = "action", "BTN", class="action-button")
```

Comment: this really works :) what is class "action-button" doing with my button under the hood?

Comment: It transforms it to an event listener. You can see the difference by inspecting the HTML of the button in your browse.

Comment: and I guess if I don't use this `class = 'action-button'` - workaround, I'll have to do a lot of manual javascript programming, right?

Comment: I honestly have no idea