# modalDialog not opening after clicking on the same row in reactable

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog, reactable

I am currently building a Shiny app where I'd allow a user to click on a row in a reactable and show a modalDialog with more info based on that row. I followed this post ([How to trigger a modalBox with observeEvent from a cell rendered button in a reactable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69593193/how-to-trigger-a-modalbox-with-observeevent-from-a-cell-rendered-button-in-a-rea)) to get the `onclick` JavaScript function.

However, when I click on the same row using this logic, nothing happens. I have to click on another row before I click back to that same row. I believe it's because `input$foo` does not change its value if the same row is being clicked.

I've tried setting `input$foo` to a different value when the `modalDialog` opens, but that has not been working either. Does anyone know how to work around this or reset that `input$foo` value after opening? I don't have a ton of experience in JavaScript. A basic Shiny example is shown below where the title of `modalDialog` displays the car name after clicking on the specific row.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(reactable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(12, align = 'center',reactableOutput("tbl"))
    )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data = reactive({
    mtcars %>% add_rownames('car')
  })
  
  output$tbl = renderReactable(
    reactable(
      data(),
      defaultPageSize = 10,
      compact = T,
      highlight = T,
      defaultColDef = colDef(headerClass = "bar-sort-header",
                             sortNALast = T, align = 'center',
                             headerVAlign = 'center',
                             vAlign = 'center',
                             minWidth = 60
      ),
      onClick = JS("function(rowInfo, colInfo) {
                              Shiny.setInputValue('foo', rowInfo.id)
                            }"),
      rowStyle = list(cursor = "pointer")
    )
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$foo, {
    print(input$foo)
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        size = 'l',
        easyClose = T,
        title = data()$car[as.numeric(input$foo)+1],
      )
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You could wait with accepting my answer, maybe someone has a better approach, since I also deal with this problem I'd be interested if there are other options :)

Answer (score 3):

I also run into this problem a lot and my approach is to set the `input$foo` to `null` after calling `showModal` so we can click again on the same row:

```r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(reactable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tags$head(
    tags$script(
    "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('update_input_foo', function(value) {
      Shiny.setInputValue('foo', null)
    });
    ")
  ),
  
  fluidRow(
    column(12, align = 'center',reactableOutput("tbl"))
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data = reactive({
    mtcars %>% add_rownames('car')
  })
  
  output$tbl = renderReactable(
    reactable(
      data(),
      defaultPageSize = 10,
      compact = T,
      highlight = T,
      defaultColDef = colDef(headerClass = "bar-sort-header",
                             sortNALast = T, align = 'center',
                             headerVAlign = 'center',
                             vAlign = 'center',
                             minWidth = 60
      ),
      onClick = JS("function(rowInfo, colInfo) {
                              Shiny.setInputValue('foo', rowInfo.id)
                            }"),
      rowStyle = list(cursor = "pointer")
    )
  )
  
  r <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$foo, {
    
    if (!is.null(input$foo)) {
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        size = 'l',
        easyClose = T,
        title = data()$car[as.numeric(input$foo)+1],
      )
    )
    
    session$sendCustomMessage("update_input_foo", 1)

    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2):

I run into this problem a lot as well, here is a simpler approach with a random value sent each time when the row is clicked.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(reactable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(12, align = 'center',reactableOutput("tbl"))
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data = reactive({
    mtcars %>% tibble::rownames_to_column('car')
  })

  output$tbl = renderReactable(
    reactable(
      data(),
      defaultPageSize = 10,
      compact = T,
      highlight = T,
      defaultColDef = colDef(headerClass = "bar-sort-header",
                             sortNALast = T, align = 'center',
                             headerVAlign = 'center',
                             vAlign = 'center',
                             minWidth = 60
      ),
      onClick = JS("function(rowInfo, colInfo) {
                              Shiny.setInputValue('foo', {id:rowInfo.id, nonce:Math.random()})
                             }"),
      rowStyle = list(cursor = "pointer")
    )
  )

  observeEvent(input$foo, {
    print(input$foo)

    id <- input$foo$id
    row_nr <- as.numeric(id)+1

    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        size = 'l',
        easyClose = T,
        title = data()$car[row_nr],
      )
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the only way to overcome this is to add the event priority to the input change.
Normally shiny inputs won't trigger an observeEvent if the value doesn't change, but you can force the behaviour by added `{ priority: 'event' }` into `Shiny.setInputValue`

Here is the full edit of your code in the question:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(reactable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(12, align = 'center',reactableOutput("tbl"))
    )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data = reactive({
    mtcars %>% add_rownames('car')
  })
  
  output$tbl = renderReactable(
    reactable(
      data(),
      defaultPageSize = 10,
      compact = T,
      highlight = T,
      defaultColDef = colDef(headerClass = "bar-sort-header",
                             sortNALast = T, align = 'center',
                             headerVAlign = 'center',
                             vAlign = 'center',
                             minWidth = 60
      ),
      onClick = JS("function(rowInfo, colInfo) {
                              Shiny.setInputValue('foo', rowInfo.id, {priority: 'event' })
                            }"),
      rowStyle = list(cursor = "pointer")
    )
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$foo, {
    print(input$foo)
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        size = 'l',
        easyClose = T,
        title = data()$car[as.numeric(input$foo)+1],
      )
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```